# ERROR SENDING FILE: error domain = mcsession code = 0 "Cannot Open file. Pen file.}

Tags: ios, swift

I tried to send a PDF in the iPhone with MutipeerConnect. The following errors appeared when running on the real machine:
Error Sending File: Error Domain = McSactive Code = 0 "Cannot Open File." UserInfo = {nslocalizedDescripting = Cannot Open file.}
code show as below:

```swift
 func sendFiles(urls: [URL]) {
        
        // 有设备连接
        if MPCService.shared.mcSession.connectedPeers.count > 0 {
            
            // 只发送给第一台设备
            if let firstPeer = MPCService.shared.mcSession.connectedPeers.first {
                
              
                for url in urls {
                    
                    //                    DispatchQueue.global().async {
                    let resourceName = url.lastPathComponent // 文件名
                    
                    let isAccessing = url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() // 开始安全访问
                    
                    MPCService.shared.mcSession.sendResource(at: url, withName: resourceName, toPeer: firstPeer) { (error) in
                        
                        //                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        if let error = error {
                            print("Error sending file: \(error)")
                        } else {
                            print("File \(resourceName) sent successfully")
                        }
                        //                        }
                        
                        //                        }
                    }
                    
                    if isAccessing {
                        url.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
                    } // 结束安全访问
                    
                }
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    AlertKitAPI.dismissAllAlerts()// 消除AlerKit进度条
                    
                    AlertKitAPI.present(
                        title: "发送文件成功!",
                        icon: .done,
                        style: .iOS17AppleMusic,
                        haptic: .success
                    )
                    
                }
            }
            
            
        }
        
        
    }
```

I tried to turn on the security access permissions:`url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()` , but it didn't help anything